# Удаление файлов с пропуском -Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть кортеж `filebrowse` с именами файлов которые надо удалить. Я использую функцию `os.remove()` она иногда останавливается на файлах которые заняты каким либо процессом. Как пропустить эти файлы?. И вывести на каких файлах она остановилась?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.access(path, mode, *, dir_fd=None, effective_ids=False, follow_symlinks=True)` - проверка доступа к объекту у текущего пользователя. Флаги: `os.F_OK` - объект существует, `os.R_OK` - доступен на чтение, `os.W_OK` - доступен на запись, `os.X_OK` - доступен на исполнение.

```
passed = set()
for file_path in file_path_tuple:
    if os.access(file_path, os.R_OK|os.X_OK):
        os.remove(file_path)
    else:
        passed.add(file_path)
print(passed)
```